# Wordpress Error "Nothing Found" caused by the Polylang plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-error-pages, polylang

The website is on CMS WordPress, and periodically, after making any edits (whether it's a change in a post/page, updating a plugin, widget, or theme file), the "Nothing Found" error occurs. This error specifically affects all sections and subcategories of the root language version except the homepage. All other language versions are not affected by this error.

The error disappears either after updating the "Permalink Settings" or by disabling the "Hide URL language information for the default language" option in the Polylang settings.
I would like to identify the cause and fix it, considering future plugin updates.